# Modrewrite url on index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created a zend framework application and the modrewrite only worked when i did:

`index.php/dashboard` for instance, accessing the dashboard module.

With that being said, I'm working on a new project (not zend framework) that requires a url of: `http://server/username`. I'm already on the impression that i need to do something like `http://server/index.php/username` being that it was the only working method for my prior zend framework project.

I have tried several htaccess solutions, and none have worked. They all go to a 404. Here is what I've tried:

`RewriteRule /([a-zA-Z]+)$ profile.php?name=$1`

`RewriteRule ^/([^/\.]+)$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L]`

`RewriteRule ^/index.php/([^/\.]+)$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L]`

`RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`

Nothing seems to be working. Can someone help?

---

EDIT = I believe the problem is with my apache server. All of these rewrite rules should work. I've looked at httpd.conf and the virtual host configurations. Any insight?

Comment: You need to be more specific about 'not working'. Are you getting a 404, a 500, or a completely unrelated page?

Comment: Out of curiosity: you are aware that `mod_rewrite` does no real magic, and just changes the way you access internal URLs externally? In other words, did you check that `/profile.php?name=Niels` worked before you tried to make `/Niels` have the same result using a rewrite? If the first doesn't work, the second can't either by definition.